# Why does this join to a temporary table slow down my query so much?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

<sup>*(You may have seen [another question I have open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857776/why-does-mysql-not-always-use-index-merge-here); as I investigate that myself, I'm posing this related but perhaps more specific question in the hopes that an answer to this will help me to arrive at an answer to that!*)</sup>

---

#### Background

Consider this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Alarms` (
  `AlarmId` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DeviceId` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `Code` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Ended` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NaturalEnd` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Pinned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Acknowledged` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `StartedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `EndedAt` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `MarkedForDeletion` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`AlarmId`),
  KEY `Key1` (`Ended`,`Acknowledged`),
  KEY `Key2` (`Pinned`),
  KEY `Key3` (`DeviceId`,`Pinned`),
  KEY `Key4` (`DeviceId`,`StartedAt`,`EndedAt`),
  KEY `Key5` (`DeviceId`,`Ended`,`EndedAt`),
  KEY `Key6` (`MarkedForDeletion`),

  KEY `KeyB` (`MarkedForDeletion`,`DeviceId`,`StartedAt`,`EndedAt`,`Acknowledged`,`Pinned`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

- `Key1`-`Key6` are from my original design which assumed I'd be able to rely on index merges (per my other question, this doesn't *seem* to be the case).
- `KeyB` is what I'm currently playing with in my investigative efforts.

Now, with a few hundred thousand rows in the database (all of which have match the `DeviceId`, `StartedAt` and `MarkedForDeletion` criteria listed below, but have `NOT NULL EndedAt` and `Pinned` = `FALSE`, so no rows actually match), the following query runs fairly quickly (~100ms) as long as I tell it to use `KeyB`:

```
SET @a = '2018-02-18 00:00:00';
SET @b = '2018-02-18 01:00:00';

SELECT * FROM `Alarms` USE INDEX (`KeyB`) WHERE
(
    `Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NULL
    AND `Alarms`.`Acknowledged` = FALSE

    AND `Alarms`.`StartedAt` < @b
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
) OR (
    `Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NOT NULL
    AND `Alarms`.`EndedAt` >= @a
    AND `Alarms`.`Pinned` = TRUE

    AND `Alarms`.`StartedAt` < @b
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
);
```

Query plan:

[image: Query plan 1]

I'd take all this to mean it's constructed to be as fast as possible so far. However, as we'll see in a moment, that doesn't appear to be the case.

---

#### The problem

Next I'm going to make things more complicated by creating a temporary table of time ranges, adding the same range as before, then joining to that table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_ranges`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `_ranges` (
    `Start` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `End`   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Start`, `End`)
);

INSERT INTO `_ranges` VALUES(@a, @b));
```

Now:

```
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`_ranges`.`Start`) AS `Start_TS`,
    COUNT(`Alarms`.`AlarmId`) AS `n`
FROM `_ranges`
LEFT JOIN `Alarms` USE INDEX (`KeyB`) ON
(
    `Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NULL
    AND `Alarms`.`Acknowledged` = FALSE

    AND `Alarms`.`StartedAt` < `_ranges`.`End`
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
) OR (
    `Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NOT NULL
    AND `Alarms`.`EndedAt` >= `_ranges`.`Start`
    AND `Alarms`.`Pinned` = TRUE

    AND `Alarms`.`StartedAt` < `_ranges`.`End`
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
)
GROUP BY `_ranges`.`Start`
```

It's still pretty good — ~150ms, and to my untrained eye this is a decent query plan:

[image: Query plan 2]

But now let's add some more time ranges:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `_ranges`;
INSERT INTO `_ranges` VALUES
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*0  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*1  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*1  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*2  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*2  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*3  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*3  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*4  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*4  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*5  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*5  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*6  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*6  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*7  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*7  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*8  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*8  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*9  SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*9  SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*10 SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*10 SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*11 SECOND)),
    (DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*10 SECOND), DATE_ADD(@a, INTERVAL 3600*12 SECOND))
;
```

The same query now takes just over a second. Query plan again:

[image: Query plan 3]

Adding more time ranges progressively slows it down, and the duration of each one doesn't seem to matter much, even though the actual results for this particular case don't pick up any `Alarms` matches:

[image: Query result 1]

In my actual use case the selection of time ranges varies according to need; for example, in one case, I need 15-minute time slices over 12 hours, and this currently takes some 5 seconds to produce. Before adding `KeyB` it was taking over 30 seconds.

If I flip the query's conditions a bit (I'll need this one too):

```
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`_ranges`.`Start`) AS `Start_TS`,
    COUNT(`Alarms`.`AlarmId`) AS `n`
FROM `_ranges`
LEFT JOIN `Alarms` USE INDEX (`KeyB`) ON
(
    `Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NULL
    AND `Alarms`.`Acknowledged` = TRUE

    AND `Alarms`.`StartedAt` < `_ranges`.`End`
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
) OR (
    `Alarms`.`EndedAt` IS NOT NULL
    AND `Alarms`.`EndedAt` >= `_ranges`.`Start`
    AND `Alarms`.`Pinned` = FALSE

    AND `Alarms`.`StartedAt` < `_ranges`.`End`
    AND `MarkedForDeletion` = FALSE
    AND `DeviceId` = UNHEX('00030000000000000000000000000000')
)
GROUP BY `_ranges`.`Start`;
```

… you can see that we are now matching some `Alarms` rows:

[image: Query result 2]

… but the performance is still about the same.

Therefore I believe the bottleneck is in the way the actual join to `_ranges` is constructed.

**Why? And how can I fix it?**

*(Above query plans obtained on MariaDB 5.5.56/CentOS 7, but solution must also work on MySQL 5.1.73/CentOS 6.)*

Comment: I can't create the time slices using aggregate functions directly because [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48170800/560648)

Comment: `but solution must also work on MySQL 5.1.73`. Well.... -> `5.1.73 (December 03, 2013)`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: CentOS 6 is still in long-term support (just about) and we have clients using it in closed networks; using "native" distro packages is preferable. 2013 isn't that long ago in the enterprise world ;)

Comment: I suppose what I _could_ do is use aggregate functions to get mini-time slices (say, a minute, as all my slices will be longer than that) then collate at the application layer..

Comment: in the sample data for _ranges, you have the value 3600*10 twice (last and last-but-one row) which *might* have an impact with the `GROUP BY`. KeyB is a multi-column index. it may be worth trying to add dedicated indexes for `StartedAt` and `EndedAt` and see if that results in a better query plan. it is probably a full scan now.

Comment: @dlatikay: Good spot - on first glance I thought it was merely a transcription error, but the ensuing screenshots tell otherwise. Will have to retest this.